# How to get particular column in zend using Left join

Tags: sql

I am new to zend framework,

Following is the plain mysql query which takes particular column from table,

```
SELECT jobs_users.id,jobs_users.first_name from jobs_users left join friends on jobs_users.id=friends.friend_id where friends.member_id=29
```

I tried with zend to implement the above query like below,

```
public function getFriendsProfileList($id){

           $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

$select = $db->select();
$select->from('jobs_users')
        ->joinLeft(
                'friends',
                'jobs_users.id=friends.friend_id',
                array('jobs_users.id','jobs_users.first_name','jobs_users.last_name','jobs_users.photo')
                )
        ->where("friends.member_id = ?", $id);
$result = $db->fetchAll($select);
return $result;

    }
```

Here i got result with all column name , not with exact column name which i have given in query.

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: How many columns you are getting now in one row and how many you want to get ??

Comment: @NAVEED  I am getting expected result with all rows from jobs_users.But i want only 'jobs_users.id','jobs_users.first_name','jobs_users.last_name','jobs_users.photo' these columns

Comment: @NAVEED  i got it working now by set $select->from('jobs_users','')

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
$select->from('jobs_users', array('jobs_users.id','jobs_users.first_name','jobs_users.last_name','jobs_users.photo'))
->joinLeft('friends', 'jobs_users.id=friends.friend_id')
->where("friends.member_id = ?", '20');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this:

```
$select = $db->select();
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$select->joinLeft('jobs_users','',array('jobs_users.id','jobs_users.first_name','jobs_users.last_name','jobs_users.photo'));
$select->joinLeft('friends','jobs_users.id=friends.friend_id', array());
$select->where("friends.member_id = ?", $id);
$result = $db->fetchAll($select);
return $result;
```

Comment: there is no from clause in your query.

Comment: Yes. But it should work. I am also using this type of method and it is working for me. I have edited my answer. Please review again. Try this and tell me if you get any error.